# How do I pass more than one argument to Proc in ruby/rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The following is giving me issue:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, 
:reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? }, 
:reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['photo_title'].blank? },
:allow_destroy => true
```

I think it's because I'm calling :reject_if twice, not 100% sure. But when ever I uncomment the photo_title reject_if line my image doesn't get upload if I select one. If I comment the line out then it does.

How can I combine both conditions into one reject_if condition? If that makes sense.

Kind regards

Comment: why don't you use an extern method to cleanly handle the logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, 
  :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? }, 
  :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['photo_title'].blank? },
  :allow_destroy => true
```

is the same as this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, {
  :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? }, 
  :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['photo_title'].blank? },
  :allow_destroy => true
}
```

The fat-arrow arguments are actually a Hash, the braces are essentially added by Ruby behind your back. A Hash doesn't allow duplicate keys so the second `:reject_if` value overwrites the first one and you end up with this:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo,
  :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['photo_title'].blank? },
  :allow_destroy => true
```

You can combine both conditions in one Proc though:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo,
  :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? || attributes['photo_title'].blank? }, 
  :allow_destroy => true
```

You could also use a separate method:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo,
  :reject_if => :not_all_there,
  :allow_destroy => true

def not_all_there(attributes)
  attributes['image'].blank? || attributes['photo_title'].blank?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :photo, 
 :reject_if => proc { |attributes| attributes['image'].blank? || attributes['photo_title'].blank?}, 
 :allow_destroy => true
```

Comment: The same thing is happening so I guess theres a deeper issue. I have set :_destroy => "1" on both of those fields so not sure why it's not working.